# Replace characters sequentially with array PHP

Tags: php

I've been orderd to localise our website. Yah.

Having issues, in places sush as our notification system.
Example:
You have 3 new messages

Id like the local string to look something like:

```
You have % new messages
```

and then pass the number and replace the % with the number.

How-ever, if I then have something where I'd want multiple numbers, like:

```
You have % new messages, and % alerts
```

I'd like to pass two numbers in an array to replace the first and second %

Example:

```
$local->get(alert.message, array(3, 4))
```

alert.message corrosponds to `You have % new messages, and % alerts`

and final output becomes: `You have 3 new messages, and 4 alerts`

Comment: Alright, and have you taken a look at [this](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: So you're looking for [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not giving you the code (agreeing to Naruto's advice), but [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) should be able to help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace` to set a limit to the number of replaces. With this, you can do the following:

```
$str = "You have % new messages, and % alerts";
$array = [3, 4];

foreach ($array as $a)
    $str = preg_replace("/%/", $a, $str, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `strtr`:

```
$str = "You have :messages new messages, and :alerts alerts";
echo strtr($str, [
    ':messages' => 5,
    ':alerts' => 10,
]);
```

Or as a function:

```
function strReplace($str, array $items) {
    return strtr($str, $items);
}
```

It is a little redundant (you could just call `strtr` directly, but it does package it up into a function.

Using named parameters makes your code a little easier to read, as well.

It is worth noting that this is not safe for security stuff. Just so you know.